# Retrieving data from Mysql and storing in option html tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

Hey guys i'm stuck on this question. What I'm trying to do is retrieve some data from MYSQL and store it in an option tag. Here is my code.

```
<?php
$user = "admin";
$password = "";
$db = "test";
$host = "localhost";
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db);

$query = "SELECT ARTIST FROM music";
$results = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die("Connection could not be established");

echo "<select name='mediaType'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    extract($row);
    echo "<option value=''>$row</option>\n";                                        
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

After preforming this function the output in the option tag is "Array" for all options in the select element. I tried storing the data from the php variable $row into an array then looping threw that array and echoing out each index in the array, but the results were the same. May someone plz provide me some guidance on this issue. Thanks all who help.

Comment: Why are you using `extract()`?

Comment: Well I would like to get all the data from the the column Artist. Other than that no reason in particular. Is there a better way. Keep in mind i'm a newb to php.

Comment: $row is an array. You have to write :  $row["id"] or  $row[columnname] (where column name is the name of the fields you have in your dzatabase) for each value you want to display

Comment: when I write extract($row['ARTIST']); is still outputs "Array" for the option tag.

Comment: @meddy `extract()` unpacks an array, creating variables using the array's keys as variable names. So, again, why are you using the function? RTFM.

Comment: Its what I used before and it worked, however, I never tried to with this concept @Sverri M. Olsen. Is there a better or correct method to use for this concept?

Comment: I see what you were getting @Sverri M. Olsen thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why not simply do:**

```
echo "<select name='mediaType'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row['ARTIST']."'>".$row['ARTIST']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the other users, `extract()` is not what you want here. `$row` is an array where the keys are your column names. Use something like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<option value="">'.$row['ARTIST'].'</option>';
}
```

Note how I changed the quotes; the array operator doesn't work within a double-quoted string.

And in the future, to inspect the contents of a variable, look into using [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php), it's great for seeing what's going on behind the scenes.

Edit: oh, and if your table has a numeric primary key ID, you should probably use that as the value for your select, to protect yourself against changing names or human-input typos.

Comment: Note that the value attribute is still empty. It'll send empty value while posting the form.